# prepare command not working with DBI

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I am trying to do this but it is not working

```
 my $sql2 = "SELECT CODE_ID,NAME_CODE,SUM(INR_COL + OUT_COL) AS \"TOTAL SUM\" FROM nwsa WHERE trunc(REPORT_DATE) = to_date('?','dd-mm-yyyy')AND CODE_ID IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)GROUP BY CODE_ID,NAME_CODE"; 
     $sth ->prepare($sql2);
     my $t= "06-01-2017";

     $sth->execute($t,'A12A','A12B','A12C','A12D','A12E','A12EB','A12F','A12G','A12I','A12O','A12U');
```

Comment: How does it fail, show the error!

Comment: cant call preapre on undefined value

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
$sth ->prepare($sql2);
```

you need:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
```

https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#prepare

Also consider the `prepare_cached` method, depending on what you are actually doing:

https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#prepare_cached